Is it possible to filter a list of data frames by the contents of another DF?
I'm looking for a way to filter the contents of each data frame in a list df_list by the contents of some single data frame containing my criteria.
In this case, I have a ton of sample data from an image, where each object in the image was identified by coordinates. I only want a specific subset of the objects, but the coordinate range of those objects changes from image to image.
Here are some example data:
image_a <- data.frame(
  X = c(1, 10),
  Y = c(5, 12),
  CritA = c("aln", "cbra"),
  CritB = c(21, 117)
)

image_b <- data.frame(
  X = c(12, 35),
  Y = c(96, 99),
  CritA = c("asdf", "bzt"),
  CritB = c(90, 105)
)
df_list <- list(ImageA = image_a, ImageB = image_b)

>df_list

$ImageA
   X  Y CritA CritB
1  1  5   aln    21
2 10 12  cbra   117

$ImageB
   X  Y CritA CritB
1 12 96  asdf    90
2 35 99   bzt   105

filter_coords <- data.frame(
  image = c(ImageA, ImageB),
  Xmin = c(2, 32),
  Ymin = c(3, 95),
  Xmax = c(12, 48),
  Ymax = c(30, 102)
)

> filter_coords
   image Xmin Ymin Xmax Ymax
1 ImageA    2    3   12   30
2 ImageB   32   95   48  102

So in this case, I'm trying to filter the rows in ImageA down to include only lines where X is between 2 and 12, and Y is between 3 and 30
$ImageA
   X  Y CritA CritB
2 10 12  cbra   117

And then ImageB down to only lines where X is between 32 and 48, and Y is between 95 and 102.
$ImageB
   X  Y CritA CritB
2 35 99   bzt   105

The direction I think this will go is filtering, somehow, using lapply() to iterate through the DFs in df_list. Where I'm stuck is pulling the matching data from filter_coords to filter each of the data frames.
I've tried variations of this to try and get started (just filtering for Y for now):
test_filtered <- lapply(df_list, function(x) filter(x, Y > filter_coords$Ymin[x] & Y < filter_coords$Ymax[x]))

And only got errors.
Is this something that's possible? Do I need to completely reformat my input data? I'm pretty new to R, and while I could do this for my data (~40 image DFs) in Excel, I'm trying to use any excuse to improve my R skills. I'm just at a loss here as nothing I've found in my googling has turned up anything I can throw at this.
*Edit: Fixed image_b input values to match

Why not bind_row your list of data frames into one, join with your criterion data and finally filter to get what you want?

and you can use join_by(image, X>=Xmin, X<=Xmax, Y>=Ymin, Y<=Ymax) directly within the inner_join() call

library(dplyr)

filter_image <- function(dataname) {
    current_filter <- filter(filter_coords, image == dataname)
    df_list[[dataname]] %>%
        semi_join(current_filter, by = join_by(between(X, Xmin, Xmax)) , between(Y, Ymin, Ymax))
}

result <- lapply(names(df_list), filter_image)
names(result) <- names(df_list)

result
#> $ImageA
#>    X  Y CritA CritB
#> 1 10 12  cbra   117
#> 
#> $ImageB
#>    X  Y CritA CritB
#> 1 35 99   bzt   105

Created on 2024-05-13 with reprex v2.1.0

Tidyverse solution assuming you have the same number of dataframes and rows of criterias in "filter_coords"`dataframe. Note that you have a typo in your original post regarding the "image_b" dataframe (wrong values).
image_a <- data.frame(
  X = c(1, 10),
  Y = c(5, 12),
  CritA = c("aln", "cbra"),
  CritB = c(21, 117)
)

image_b <- data.frame(
  X = c(12, 35),
  Y = c(96, 99),
  CritA = c("asdf", "bzt"),
  CritB = c(90, 105)
)

df_list <- list(ImageA = image_a, ImageB = image_b)
filter_coords <- data.frame(
  image = c("ImageA", "ImageB"),
  Xmin = c(2, 32),
  Ymin = c(3, 95),
  Xmax = c(12, 48),
  Ymax = c(30, 102)
)

### Packages
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

### For each row of filter_coords filter each dataframe
out=map(1:nrow(filter_coords),
    ~filter(df_list[[.x]],between(X,filter_coords[.x,2],filter_coords[.x,4])&
              between(Y,filter_coords[.x,3],filter_coords[.x,5])))
names(out)<-names(df_list)

Output :
$ImageA
   X  Y CritA CritB
1 10 12  cbra   117

$ImageB
   X  Y CritA CritB
1 35 99   bzt   105


Thank you! I've edited my original question to make sure that image_b is correct and I'll give this solution a try.


Is it possible to filter a list of data frames by the contents of another DF?

Yes, this can be done -- even very compact.
1. With Map()
from base R; no need for external packages. The trick is to split filter_coords on image:
Map(\(x, y) subset(x, with(y, Y %in% Ymin:Ymax & X %in% Xmin:Xmax)),
    df_list, split(filter_coords, filter_coords$image))

$ImageA
   X  Y CritA CritB
2 10 12  cbra   117

$ImageB
   X  Y CritA CritB
2 35 99   bzt   105

Notice that, you might need to order your data and preserve the order while splitting, use splitKeepOrder = \(x, f, ...) split(x, factor(f, levels = unique(f)), ...) then.
2. With {dplyr}1,
demonstrating what @Limey and @langtang suggest in their comments:
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df_list, .id = "image") |>
  inner_join(filter_coords, 
             by = join_by(image == image, X >= Xmin, X <= Xmax, Y >= Ymin, Y <= Ymax)) |>
  select(image, names(first(df_list)))

   image  X  Y CritA CritB
1 ImageA 10 12  cbra   117
2 ImageB 35 99   bzt   105

1 This and related joins require more effort in base R.

Data used
It appears there is a typo in your toy data, hence here a corrected version:
image_a <- data.frame(
  X = c(1, 10),
  Y = c(5, 12),
  CritA = c("aln", "cbra"),
  CritB = c(21, 117))
image_b <- data.frame(
  X = c(12, 35),
  Y = c(96, 99),
  CritA = c("asdf", "bzt"),
  CritB = c(90, 105))
df_list <- list(ImageA = image_a, ImageB = image_b)
filter_coords <- data.frame(
  image = c("ImageA", "ImageB"),
  Xmin = c(2, 32),
  Ymin = c(3, 95),
  Xmax = c(12, 48),
  Ymax = c(30, 102))


It took me a few minutes to work out what all was going on, but it's a nice compact solution. I ran it and checked the solution and noticed some inaccuracies in the results though. If I understand correctly, this solution doesn't match the image name in the filter_coords df with the name of the data frame in df_list? So there should be an additional sort step so that they are all sorted into the same order before running the filter? In addition, I guess it should be applied only in the case where the filter_coords df has the same number of entries as df_list?
I hope I understand correctly!

Well, the important thing about toy data: it should mimic your real data. It seems like this is not the case, please adapt accordingly and we can have a look.
